# Why CSS hover state removed?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a simple navigation and sub navigation(activated after hover on parent element), But In my project when I hover on subnavigation's last child the active class removed. Unable to figured out the problem. Please help.

Here is the code and JSFIDDLE

HTML

```
<div class="menu-nav">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="current_user"> <span class="user_image"></span>Hi, Inderjeet<b class="caret"></b></a></li>
        <li><span class="bookings">Bookings<b class="caret"></b>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu">
                <li><a href="#">Booking 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Booking 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Booking 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span></li>
        <li><span class="hosting">Hosting<b class="caret"></b>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu">
                <li><a href="#">Booking 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Booking 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Booking 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span></li>


    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-nav{float:left; }
.menu-nav > ul > li{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; -webkit-vertical-align: middle; -moz-vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 25px;   } 
.menu-nav > ul > li > a, .menu-nav > ul > li > span{color:#4d4d4d; font-size: 16px; padding:5px; position: relative;}

ul.dropdown_menu{display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; padding-top:40px; padding-bottom: 20px; width: 200px;}
ul.dropdown_menu > li > a {color:#4d4d4d; padding:10px; display: block; background:#fff;}
ul.dropdown_menu.activemenu{display: block;}
ul.dropdown_menu.activemenu li a:hover{background:red;}
```

jQuery

```
$('.menu-nav ul li span').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul.dropdown_menu').toggleClass('activemenu');
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bzLfu3er/)

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue is.  Fiddle appears to work fine, there's no difference when hovering over first child compared with last child.  Can you explain what it is doing and what you want it to do please?

Comment: In Fiddle it is working perfect but in my project it is not working..I have also removed Reset css

Comment: And the fiddle matches the code in the question?  Exactly what are we supposed to be helping with?   "I've got some other code that I'm not going to show you that doesn't work, but here's slightly related code that works fine" - so what?

Comment: So what are you doing differently in your code compared with the working code?

Answer (score 0):

You should do a hover to the li element not to the span:

```
$('.menu-nav > ul > li').hover(function(){
```

and the ul should not be in the span in the html

Comment: Hi, I have tried to hover the li but it's not working

Comment: which browser are you using and which operating system.

Comment: MAC OSX 10.10, Chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

**Hi now try to this way**

**[mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)** and **[mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)**

```
$(".menu-nav ul li span").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find('ul.dropdown_menu').addClass('activemenu');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find('ul.dropdown_menu').removeClass('activemenu');
    }
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bzLfu3er/1/)**

---

**Or now you can used to css**

```
.menu-nav ul li span:hover ul.dropdown_menu{
    display: block;
}
```